# Migrate Elastic Beanstalk logs to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring boot application running on Elastic beans stalk so whenever i try to view the log there is only one option that view 100 line log or full logs . Also whenever the new build happens the old log gets destroyed so this way i am not able to keep track of my old logs ? So that's why i want to move all the logs periodically or per build wise into S3 so that i can keep track of those logs

Comment: isnt your logs are stored in cloudwatch?

Comment: currently it is not stored

Answer (score 1):

You can enable **streaming of logs** to CLoudWatch Logs:

- [Streaming instance logs to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.streaming)

Before you do, make sure you have necessary permissions attached to your **EB instance role**, as per the above link.

You can enable the streaming in the console:

[image]

And then here as well:

[image]

This will give CloudWatch Logs like these ones:

[image]

Once your log data is being stream to CW Logs, you can create **subscription filter** to Firehose and then to S3:

- [Example 3: Subscription Filters with Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample)

Comment: this is creating every-time a new instance after deployment

Comment: @VatsalRahul Its continues stream of logs to CloudWatch Logs. So it will persist over deployments.

Comment: but it will increase the cost also if everytime new instance will get created

Comment: @VatsalRahul Yes. If you don't want to use CloudWatch Logs, then you have to create your own solution for that. A `cron` job perhaps with custom script to copy logs to s3.

Comment: No i am not saying about the cost of cloudwatch logs , i am saying the cost of aws ec2 instances which is getting created everytime

Comment: @VatsalRahul Sorry, I don't understand. Which instances? EB instances are only created when you create yoru EB environment and during scaling events if you have load-balanced environment. On single-instance type environment, you have only one instance.

Comment: OK so it might have scaled up and created one more environment . The only thing which i am not understanding now is do i need to create my own S3 bucket , where i will customise this data

Comment: @VatsalRahul You can control the maximum number of instances you can have in your load-balanced environment. For example, set it to max 2 instances. If you choose to use CW Logs as in my answer, then you have to create a Firehose stream and own bucket. Alternatively, you can manually [export CW Logs to S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html), without the need for Firehose.

Comment: So In kinesis if i create a data stream it is asking me the buffer time and max is 900 seconds so if i am correct it means it will look save the log for 15 mins and then use another file to store the data , but ideally i would like to store a cloudwatch log for about 4 hours